# My Function is not reading my dynamic textbox values

Tags: php, textbox

Im having a hard time figuring why my function is not inserting my dynamic textbox values while others are working correctly. Ill just show the codes of my dynamic textbox.

Here is my register.php - i think its fine here because i can add and delete textboxes. Then if I will press submit it does my doRegister function.

```
require_once './library/config.php';
require_once './library/functions.php';

if (isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['lastname'])) {
$result = doRegister();
if ($result != '') {
    $errorMessage = $result;
   }
}
?>
```

here is my functions.php

```
function doRegister()
{
$fname  = $_POST['firstname'];
$mname  = $_POST['middlename'];
$lname  = $_POST['lastname'];
$email  = $_POST['email'];  
$phone  = $_POST['phone'];
$cphone = $_POST['cphone'];
$dob    = $_POST['dob'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];

$add    = $_POST['address'];
$city   = $_POST['city'];
$state  = $_POST['state'];
$zip    = (int)$_POST['zipcode'];
$typeres    = $_POST['type_res'];   
$liveyear   = $_POST['live_year'];

$pwd    = $_POST['password'];

$type   = $_POST['acctype'];
$pin    = (int)$_POST['pin'];

$errorMessage = '';


$sql = "SELECT fname FROM tbl_users WHERE fname = '$fname' and lname = '$lname'";
$result = dbQuery($sql);
if (dbNumRows($result) == 1) {
    $errorMessage = 'Username is already exist, please try another name.';
    return $errorMessage;
}


$accno = rand(9999999999, 99999999999);
$accno = strlen($accno) != 10 ? substr($accno, 0, 10) : $accno;


$images = uploadProductImage('pic', SRV_ROOT . 'images/thumbnails/');
$thumbnail = $images['thumbnail'];
$insert_id = 0; 
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_users (fname, lname, pwd, email, phone, gender, is_active, utype, pics, bdate, mname, cpnum, years_in_city, civil_stat, religion, educ_attain, emp_stat, voter, mother_name, mother_maiden, mother_occu, father_name, father_maiden, father_occu, no_sibling, fam_income, type_res)
        VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', PASSWORD('$pwd'), '$email', '$phone', '$gender', 'FALSE', 'USER', '$thumbnail', NOW(), '$mname', '$cphone', '$liveyear', '$cstat', '$religion', '$high_edu', '$emp_stat', '$voter', '$moname', '$momaid', '$mooccu', '$faname', '$famaid', '$faoccu', '$nosib', '$aveincome', '$typeres')"; 
dbQuery($sql);
$insert_id = dbInsertId();
```

Now this is my codes for inserting dynamic textbox values.

```
$itemcount = count($_POST["item_name"]);
$itemvalues = 0;

$query = "INSERT INTO item (item_name,item_price) VALUES ";
$queryValue = "";
for($i=0;$i<$itemCount;$i++) {
  if(!empty($_POST["item_name"][$i]) || !empty($_POST["item_price"][$i])) {
     $itemValues++;
 if($queryValue!="") $queryValue .= ",";
 $queryValue .= "('" . $_POST["item_name"][$i] . "', '" .      $_POST["item_price"][$i] . "')";
  }
  }
  $sql = $query.$queryValue;
  if($itemValues!=0) {
  dbQuery($sql);
  }

  header('Location: aregister.php');
  exit;

  }
```

Any help comment advice would be greatly appreciated! thank you very very much stackoverflow community!

Comment: check for errors; you're not doing that.

Comment: I see no code which produces these "dynamic textboxes". Is your textbox HTML even valid? What does the HTML look like if you press `Ctrl+U` to view the source code in your browser. Is your PHP even receiving any data? `echo '<pre>'.print_r($_POST, true).'</pre>';` is going to answer a lot of these questions. Also `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your PHP scripts will help to debug some of these issues.